# Weird and Wonky hair

Tags: particles, hair

[image: screenshot 1]

I have a problem with combing... When I comb the hair particles, it gets all wonky and weird...

[image: screenshot 2 wonky]

It looks like the hair isn't connected to the mesh though.

I tried different meshes, but they were perfectly fine... I've tried everything to solve this problem but I couldn't find a solution... Can anyone please help me?

file: [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot! This method really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the strange behavior when combing is the *Comb Brush* options **(1)**. You need to tick

- *Preserve* `[X]` *Strand Lengths* and
- *Preserve* `[X]` *Root Positions*

Then the hair will keep its length and the roots will no longer move. (Press <kbd>N</kbd> in the viewport to open the side panel.)

Additionally, I would enable the `[X]` *Deflect Emitter* option and increase the distance value **(2)**. This will prevent the hair from going into the head during combing.

And to see the hair structure better, you can also enable `[X]` *Ambient Occlusion* in the Eevee render settings **(3)**.

[image: screenshot comb tool settings]